# Is there a font / addon for text with decent topology?

Tags: mesh, add-on, topology, procedural

I've been using blender for a little over a year now, mainly as a tool to experiment with text distortion, animation, etc. It's obviously a great program for many things but the built in text-to-mesh conversion almost always results in sloppy topology. For a while now I've been considering creating a library of 'fixed' letters. Although this isn't a bad option, I'd like to see what else has been done in this field before I jump in. I'm open to checking out any solution or workflow to help speed up this process.

Comment: Hey :). This is a very interesting topic. I can share my way of dealing with this, if you're interested. However I only work with static text, no deforming and stuff :).